# Append Pymongo data from list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have position data from MongoDB in a dataframe, which contains a list filled with dictionaries. I am now trying to read position data fromthe dictionaries into a dataframe. I have created a new dataframe with the columns (posX, posY and posZ). Now i want to read in the data, but I have the following problem. If I want to add data via the index, it takes the position data from the last MongoDB document for all entries. What do I have to do so that the correct position data is displayed for each row?

I got the dictionaries from the following DataFrame with this code

```
for i in range(0, 3, +1):
    y = df.loc[i,'position.vars']
```

(I deleted unnecessary data like "key":"Positiondaten" with the del command.)

| Time | Returncode | position.vars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.02.2017 13:01 | OK | [{"key": "Positionsdaten", "value": "1", "vartype": 1}, {"key": "PositionX", "value: 11", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionY", "value: 11", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionZ", "value: 11", "vartype" 1}] |
| 02.02.2017 13:05 | OK | {"key": "Positionsdaten", "value": "1", "vartype": 1}, {"key": "PositionX", "value: 0", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionY", "value: 0", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionZ", "value: 0", "vartype" 1}] |
| 02.02.2017 13:09 | OK | {"key": "Positionsdaten", "value": "1", "vartype": 1}, {"key": "PositionX", "value: 33", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionY", "value: 66", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionZ", "value: 99", "vartype" 1}] |

After that I tried to append the data from Y to df2.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = ["posX", "posY", "posZ"])
for i in range(0, 3, +1):
    y = df.loc[i,'position.vars'] 
    print(y)
    df2["posX"] = y[0]["value"]
    df2["posY"] = y[1]["value"]
    df2["posZ"] = y[2]["value"]
```

Currently my DataFrame looks like that

| posX | posY | posZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 66 | 99 |
| 33 | 66 | 99 |
| 33 | 66 | 99 |

But the DataFrame should look like that

| posX | posY | posZ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 33 | 66 | 99 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding [i] to

df2["posX"]**[i]** = y[0]["value"]